# KO Grid is able to see the array but is not able to show me the Real grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to use KnockOut Grid to populate some data. It binds to the ObservableArray all fine but it is not populating the grid.

I am not sure what am I missing here.

I am loading jsfiddle for you to take a look:http://jsfiddle.net/sf4p3/6/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/sf4p3/14/

I changed `data: myObsArray()` to `data: myObsArray`, added reference to Knockout as a Managed Resource and switched the Framework to jQuery, and added the CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I am not sure why we had to change the framework? I mean I thought since it has inherent compatibility with Jquery, what we needed explicitly was to specify as a framework. Anyways, your solution works so no meaning in me whining about it. Thank you so much :).

Comment: jsFiddle offers a choice of Frameworks to load, including jQuery.  It also allows you to choose Knockout, but then you lose jQuery (unless you bring it in as a Managed resource).  I find it very confusing too... as they have mixed MVC / MVVM frameworks in with general JS frameworks.  You will often want a combination... so hopefully they will switch to a multi-select model soon.

Answer (score 0):

You need jquery for the grid to work your fiddle doesnt have jquery

Comment: I thought fiddle comes loaded with JQuery. However, I added it but still no luck...